# Offline install of packages

Tags: 14.04, apt

How I could download these packages:

```
libmm-glib0
dnsmasq-base
iputils-arping
```

My ubuntu machine haven't internet connection since 13.05.2016 updates. So I have tried find a solution how to download those packages on my Windows and then with the USB stick move them in the Ubuntu and install them in there.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Download**

You can find packages [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/) and download them manually. Ensure that your version is properly picked (trusty)

- libmm-glib0
  http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libs/libmm-glib0
- dnsmasq-base
  http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/dnsmasq-base
- iputils-arping
  http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/iputils-arping

**Installation**

You can install packages manually like that

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/local/file
```

**Final note**

Wouldn't it be easier to fix your internet access on the ubuntu machine first?

A possible entry in `/etc/network/interfaces` for a wired device eth0 could look like this (IPv4 & static).

```
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100   
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Would be. I have tried to fix it whole day by using different methods but none of those worked for me. One of those method was to download network-manager and install it but when I tried that it throws the errors that those above mentioned packages aren't installed. So I try now to install those packages in Ubuntu and try install the network-manager after that. It worked for somebody at least. I'm pretty desperate. I really hope this solve the internet issue. Dunno.

Comment: is the network device properly configured in '/etc/network/interfaces'?

Comment: Well in my /interfaces are two rows : auto lo & iface lo inet loopback. I have tried modify that today couple of times but none of those worked for me either. Would you have suggests?

Comment: Hi, i added an example config for a wired eth0 device to my answer - hope that helps.